# Regex to remove everything after a specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-replace

I am trying to make a PHP regex preg_replace in order to remove everything after a specific string.Lets say I have an article, and at the end of every article there is a specific pattern of words that the article always ends. As following.

Input string:

> *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vestibulum pellentesque egestas. Sed quis velit eros. Phasellus vitae, euismod lectus nec, auctor libero. In venenatis sapien id nunc varius vehicula./Site.com/ **Risus mt 12/04/2015, ora 20:56** Tags: sapien lectus kalon fames laoreet*

Desired output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vestibulum pellentesque egestas. Sed quis velit eros. Phasellus vitae, euismod lectus nec, auctor libero. In venenatis sapien id nunc varius vehicula./Site.com/

Consequently I want to remove the pattern and everything after the pattern in input string which is in bold. "**Risus më 12/04/2015, ora 20:56**" since it will always be the same and follow a date and time, a digit format.

I am trying to do something like the code below, but I am unable to build the regex without getting errors since I am not sure on the correct syntax of the desired pattern.

```
$desired_string = preg_replace('\^Risus m.\s\d\d\D\d\d\D\d\d\d\d\\D\s(ora)','',$string);
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex to delete something after a marker in the text up to the end, you need to use `.*?`. So, you can use something like this:

```
\s*Risus\s+m.\s+\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d+,\s+ora.*$
```

PHP code:

```
$re = "/\\s*Risus\\s+m.\\s+\\d{2}\\D\\d{2}\\D\\d+,\\s+ora.*$/"; 
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vestibulum pellentesque egestas. Sed quis velit eros. Phasellus vitae, euismod lectus nec, auctor libero. In venenatis sapien id nunc varius vehicula./Site.com/ Risus mt 12/04/2015, ora 20:56 Tags: sapien lectus kalon fames laoreet"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM3zN3/2).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Everything worked great. 

As I am trying to understand the Regex pattern,  

\\s*  ~ zero or more occurrences of whitespace
\\s+ ~ one or more occurrences of whitespace
\\d{2} ~ two digits
\\D ~ non digit character 
\\d+ ~ one or more occurrences of digits
$ end of string?

ora.* ~ i dont understand this, why we are using here the dot, when there is actually a space??
THe changes that I had to make in my PHP code were, that I had to add an additional dot here **\\s+m.. ** since I had a special character there.Otherwise it would not work.

Comment: All is correct, and `.*` just means "match any symbol, 0 or more repetitions, but a newline up to the end of the string `$`". So, `.` also matches a space.